# Using a jQuery variable as an id element

Tags: jquery, html

I've got a jQuery variable:

```
var Classofentry = $('#upload_form option[class]').attr("class");
```

which the console shows to be "animal_species" and I'd like to use it in an id reference like such:

```
$(Classofentry).append("<option value='" + data + "'selected=\"selected\">" + data + "</option>"); // This might work ...
```

(The above doesn't do the trick and is just a guess.)  I had it working hardwired as

```
 $('#animal_species').append("<option value='" + data + "'selected=\"selected\">" + data + "</option>"); // This might work ...
```

where "animal_species" is the id.  Is there any way to do this?  I've also tried:

```
$("#".Classofentry).append("<option value='" + data + "'selected=\"selected\">" + data + "</option>"); // This might work ...
```

Comment: You seem to be confused about the differences between PHP and JavaScript; in the former string-concatenation is the `.` character, in the latter it's a `+`.

Comment: Yes!  I'm confused about a lot things!  :-)  Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So close:

```
$("#" + Classofentry).append("<option value='" + data + "'selected=\"selected\">" + data + "</option>");
```

String concatenation uses the `+`, not `.`

Answer (score 1):

Use `+` to append strings

```
$("#" + Classofentry)
```

Javascript uses `+` for string concatenation.